# @font-face not work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Have a some trouble whit **@font-face** in Firefox.

```
@font-face{
font-family:'PopularScript';
src:url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/eot/PopularScript.eot');
src:url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/eot/PopularScript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/wof/PopularScript.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/ttf/PopularScript.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/otf/PopularScript.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('http://static.dubrovka.dn.ua/svg/PopularScript.svg#PopularScript') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

It work's in any browser except Firefox.

Comment: this is test solution, no problem.

Comment: didnt even open properly on firefox. buddy! optimize it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't allow cross-domain font loading for security. Here are some solutions: http://www.red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default