# @font-face not displayed in Chrome (Windows)

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

I use three different fonts on my page, all of them are brilliantly displayed in different browsers, but one of them does not work in Chrome (Windows only. It work on Chrome MAC OS X&Linux).
First, there was an error "Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application / octet-stream:" I fix this error by adding in .htaccess following code:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

but my font is not displayed.
My CSS and font:

```
@font-face{
font-family:'PopularScript';
src:url('http://test.dubrovka.dn.ua/stc/eot/PopularScript.eot');
src:url('http://test.dubrovka.dn.ua/stc/eot/PopularScript.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('http://test.dubrovka.dn.ua/stc/wof/PopularScript.woff') format('woff'),
    url('http://test.dubrovka.dn.ua/stc/ttf/PopularScript.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('http://test.dubrovka.dn.ua/stc/svg/PopularScript.svg#PopularScript') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: this one seems to be working fine with Chrome (v24.0.1312.52 m) **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vf4gq/)** ... oddly doesn't work with Firefox v18.0.1  :D

Comment: ... ok I saw your post regarding Firefox, no issue then.

Comment: What is this? The code works on Chrome, and there is a much earlier question about this not working on Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445516/font-face-not-work-in-firefox. So please close this question or clarify.

Comment: Ок, this works on Chrome MAC OS X but not work in Chrome Windows/Linux. It works on Firefox  MAC OS X  but not work in Firefox Windows/Linux. I use Font Squirrel for generate @font-face kit and it does not repeat of the earlier question. I use 3 different fonts and broken only one of three fonts.

Comment: UPD. I fix trouble in Firefox Windows/Linux & Chrome Linux. Font Squirrel delete from font Cyrillic. I convert this font using font2web, but Steel have a problem in Chrome Windows, it download font, but not response it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved. Font Squirrel are broken my font, so I used [fontface.codeandmore.com](http://fontface.codeandmore.com)  service, his @ font-face kit perfectly displayed on any browser including Chrome (Windows). Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of quirks in the ways fonts are handled across browsers & platforms. I would recommend using a default font from a place such as [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) & look at their coding.  Mimic it if need be, but they create nice CSS rulesets that allow for decent cross-browser font display.

Comment: Problem in in Chrome (Windows only. It work on Chrome MAC OS X&Linux)